# How to create a one-to-one relationship in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a one-to-one relationship between two tables A & B in SQL Server 2017, what will be the best solution?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to enforce a one to one relationship, the option I see is to set the primary key of one the table as a foreign key to the other table.

```
Table A

PK: idA

Table B

PK: idA (FK on [TableA])
```

Otherwise, you can simply merge the tables.

Answer (score 1):

Use FOREIGN KEY to establish the relationship and a unique index to limit it to one.